# What's the easiest way to get photos from multiple people per day?

Tags: photo-management, sharing

I want to begin managing the Smugmug account of my child's summer camp.  They have lots of photos every day (taken by 30 or more counselors on different types of devices).. and, they never get around to going through them and posting them in a timely way.  I want to volunteer my services to do very simple photo editing and daily posting of the photos to Smugmug. (which is not getting done right now). I want to do this from my home, however. I don't want to live at the camp for 4 weeks!  I'm trying to figure out the best option for all those counselors sending me their pictures every day... in a way that I can access them all and add them to my photos app on my MacBook. The key is that it's easy for them to use from whatever device they have.

Comment: Are they taking the photos with smart phones or dedicated cameras? Do they have Internet access at the camp?

Comment: Good questions!  I would think they are taking them with smart phones and that they do have internet access.  However, I am not certain of the process.  They have strict "no technology at camp" policies for the campers.. but, I'm hoping the counselors are allowed technology.  I am going up there this weekend.  Until I know the answers to your questions, however, I can't really go any further with solving the problem.  THANKS for pointing out the obvious! :)

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox or Google Drive is probably the easiest. I'd go with Dropbox personally. I've seen it used by dozens of photographers for this sort of thing. You give everyone access to a specific folder and they drop the pictures in when they're done. Those pictures will sync to your computer's copy of the folder.

That's not the most secure solution, but it is the easiest if your photographers aren't malicious. If they are malicious they could take other peoples' photos off, for example. If you want a more secure solution you could give each photographer their own folder.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I was thinking Dropbox might work best, but it's always good to confirm that what you're thinking is correct. I greatly appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I use pcloud as cloud storage and one feature they offer is so called ["File requests"](https://www.pcloud.com/features/file-sharing.html), which is exactly the feature you're describing:

> Easily receive files from anyone directly to your pCloud account by sending file requests. Your recipients will be able to upload files without gaining access to your account. Everything will be organized in one place for your convenience.

So you would send a link to these people and they wouldn't be able to delete other people's photos, then you have the photos from everyone in one place. You can also synchronise the folder on your desktop (including on macOS), so you can manage the content on your computer.